# Gait Data Analysis assistance

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I am conducting an experiment for my University Project using the Gyroscope sensor on a smartwatch to analyse 4 individuals Gait Data and create a model to recognise new data inputted.

I have obtained my Gyro data (XYZ) but I am not very knowledgeable on how to process the data and apply any ML models.. if anyone has experience of this and is willing to help that would be amazing!

I can happily provide more info or share some files also if people want to give me a demonstration on how they do this!

Thanks guys and girls.